# DoesUserHavePermissions returning false, when user have view permission?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I have site collection and iterating user permissions for each subsites underneath. I have see couple sites have permissions to see. But when i do in the code level (below code) giving results false.

I don't know have to get his permissions other than this.  When I go to url he has permission to see.

Please help me out.

```
    sweb.DoesUserHavePermissions(suser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.ViewPages |
 SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks if the user has all three View permissions, which apparently isn't the case. If you just want to check if he has the most basic access, then you should check for SPBasePermissions.Open

Comment: I tried SPBasePermissions.Open, But doesn't work. This is FBA based site collection. 'SPMember' is the role defined and this user has this role. This role has access to the site.